# How do I use an "or" condition in a <%# Eval('column')%> inline statement?

Tags: c#

Here is what I tried but it was not well received by my my compiler:

```
<%#(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString()) || ((Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString().Length = 4) ? "N/A" : Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT"))%>
```

I want to check to see if the string is null or empty or if the length is equal to 4 and if so then `("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString` will read "N/A". How do I do this?

Comment: You should quote the condition (X || X)

Comment: is this in ASP.Net/Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close!
Change the equals sign to a double equals and fix the parenthesis:
`((Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString().Length == 4))`

Answer (score 5):

Looks like a parenthesis mismatch to me.

```
((Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString().Length = 4)
```

..........................................................................................                 ^ right there

You could also just remove the unnecessary opening parenthesis.

And as pointed out by Omada, `Length = 4` needs to be `Length == 4`

I like to expand out my inlines to avoid these issues. Like so:

```
(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString()) 
    || ((Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString().Length = 4)
    ? "N/A" 
    : Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT")
)
```

Ideally the parenthesis mismatch on the 2nd line would be more obvious.

I like Karl's method much better. If an inline is that big, it shouldn't be an inline.

Answer (score 3):

Make a method on your page instead of fighting with the run-time hide and seek errors of programming in the markup, like this:

```
public string GetPhoneExtension(string phoneExtension)
{
    if((String.IsNullOrEmpty(phoneExtension) || (phoneExtension.Length == 4))
    {
        return "N/A";
    }

    return phoneExtension;
}
```

Now in your markup you can call this function, like this:

```
<%# GetPhoneExtension(Eval("WK_PHONE_EXT").ToString())%>
```

This gives you the power of IntelliSense in Visual Studio and compile-time checks, instead of run-time checks for most issues. It also produces cleaner markup in my opinion and you only have to write the `Eval()` call once, reduces the chance of making a typo in the other `Eval()` calls.

Comment: I will...Im being lazy :P